# Iterating through an implementation of a Linked List Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list, nodes

So I read several posts regarding this subject but they all refer to iterating through a linked list that is already implemented by Java; for example, `LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();`. And then goes on to say use a for loop to iterate through the linked list. However, I'm trying to implement my own linked list and I'm not sure how to iterate through them. In other words, I have the following code:

```
class Node {
    private Node next = null; 
    private int data; 

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d; 
    }

    void appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d); 
        Node n = this; 
        while(n.next != null) {
            n = n.next; 
        }
        n.next = end; 
    }

    void print() {
        Node n = this; 
        while(n.next != null) {
            System.out.println(n); 
            n = n.next; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Node x = new Node(4); 
        x.appendToTail(5); 
        x.print(); 
    }   
}
```

The `print()` function that I had written is my effort in trying to iterate through the linked list. But, it is not working. Anybody know how to iterate through the linked list, given your own implementation of the linked list?

Comment: Elaborate _But, it is not working_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
while(n.next != null)
```

to

```
while(n != null)
```

because inside the loop you are printing the current *node* `n` and then pointing it to its next *node* by: `n = n.next;`

Comment: Thank you! I just have to also make sure that I do `System.out.println(n.data)`.

Comment: Aye, you should print `node.data` and you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking `n` for null, not `n.next()`::

```
while(n != null)
```

but you have all the aspects of a `for` loop (initial state, termination condition and iteration expression), so this can better be expressed as a `for` loop:

```
for (Node n = this; n != null; n = n.next)
    System.out.println(n.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether current node is `null` or not, not the next node. Because you will miss the last node of the list in that way, `next` part will be `null` for last node and loop would not execute.

You need to print `data` part of the node. You have not defined the `toString` method for your Node class.

```
void print() {
  Node n = this;
  while(n != null) {
    System.out.println(n.data);
    n = n.next;
  }
}
```

You can define the `toString` as below for your `Node` class, then you can directly print the `Node` object in `System.out` statement.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Node{" +
      ", data=" + data +
      '}';
}
```